# Add JSON to option values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been working with PHP for a while. I just started learning how to work with JSON.

I was able to create a PHP file that returns JSON.  In my main file, I reference the PHP file and get the JSON objects.

I can display the objects in a dropdown select menu like this:

```js
 $.getJSON( "folder/services.php", function( data )
 {
   $.each(data, function(index, item)
   {
     $('#service').append($("<option>" + item.SERVICE + "</option>"));
   });
 });
```

The above code works fine.  I can display the SERVICE values in the dropdown SELECT options.

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the SERVICE into the VALUE of the OPTION.  I hope I am saying that correctly.

Typically, the OPTION tag would look like this:

```html
 <option value="SERVICE_A">Service A</option>
 <option value="SERVICE_B">Service B</option>
 ...
```

But since I'm using JSON, I am not sure how to get the value into the OPTION.

I attempted to use PHP inside of the JQuery, but was unsuccessful.  I'll show you what I attempted:

```js
 $('#service').append($("<option value='".+ item.SERVICE +."'>" + item.SERVICE + "</option>"));
```

****** EDIT ******

I attempted this piece of code submitted by LShetty below:

```
 $.getJSON( "folder/services.php", function( data )
 {
   var strToAppend = "";
   $.each(data, function(index, item)
   {
     strToAppend += $("<option/>",
     {
       'value': item.SERVICE,
       'text': item.SERVICE
     });
   });
   $('#service').append(strToAppend);
 });
```

I only came up blank with this code.  Does anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: I see your problem. Check your append. The quotes are incorrect. Should be "<option>" + item.SERVICE + "</option>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. Don't try to use `.` for concatentation in JS, though; it's a PHP thing. And `.+` doesn't work in either language.

A safer, more jQuery-ish way to do this (it will work when `"`, `'`, `<`, etc. are present in the `SERVICE` value):

```
$('<option>').
  attr('value', item.SERVICE).
  text(item.SERVICE).
  appendTo($('#service'));
```

Comment: In more advanced code it would be better to use something like $('<option>').attr('value', item.id).text(item.name) to be both more user-friendly and server-friendly.

Comment: Using your code above, I have 2 questions.  One...does the OPTION tag need to have a closing OPTION tag?  Secondly, what if I want to appendTo another dropdown list? Please advise.

Comment: 1. No. The first line creates a complete option tag, then we add attributes and text. 2. If you want to append to a different dropdown, use that list's `id` instead. If you want to append it to this list *and* another, replace that last semicolon with `.clone().appendTo($('#someotherlist'));`

Comment: Thank you.  I will attempt this and let you know if it works.

Comment: I have attempted this and it was successful.  I can go to Chrome's console/debugger window and see all of the values in the dropdown.  Thank you, good sir.

Answer (score 0):

Paul has the answer above. This is more of an optimization take. Modifying DOM in a loop is costly! it may be okay in this specific question as I only see 2 items. Hence, always construct your string outside of the loop and append all at once when you are ready.

```
var strToAppend = "";
$.each(data, function(index, item) {

  strToAppend += $("<option/>", {
    'value': item.SERVICE,
    'text': item.SERVICE
  });
});

$('#service').append(strToAppend);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks.  I will attempt this method as well.

Comment: Same question I asked Paul Roub, using your method, how would I append the same objects and values to another dropdown list?  Please advise.

Comment: Same answer as Paul :) $("#yourID1,#yourID2,.yourClass").append(strToAppend);

Comment: I'm trying to show you the code that I used.  Give me a second.

Comment: LShetty, please see my edit above.  Please advise what I did wrong.  The dropdown box only came up blank.